# H.264 Streamed Video Works in Chrome 23 but not Chrome 24, different request headers... same cherrypy backend

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

On the site I'm currently working on, we use html5 video with h.264. If it's not available we use a flash fallback. The flash fallback is working just fine in both chrome 23 and 24, but the html5 video only works in chrome 23.

I opened the video file in it's own tab (which chrome then has a simple bootstrap snippet of html to play it) in each version of chrome and saved the request and response information. It makes three requests actually but I find teh first one to be the most interesting. Here is the header information for the request and response for both.

Chrome 23:

```
Request:
URL:http://localhost:8040/media/preview/ab0eca40ffee4f/c268a6240b08ff/MP4_360
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:beaker.session.id=c59137ff184428045f317d6b2385aa384    4c30f
Host:localhost:8040
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
-------------------------------
Response Headersview source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="2af3dc86e4fae33370c268a6240b08ff"
Content-Length:5817287
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Wed, 06 Feb 2013 15:51:25 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 07 Dec 2012 19:47:51 GMT
Server:CherryPy/3.2.0
```

Chrome 24:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8040/media/preview/ef5a0220219b8e0/a4fe5f21c26f/MP4_360
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:beaker.session.id=5c080dc2b3343dc725ea368dae30cb1bc324
Host:localhost:8040
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.68 Safari/537.17
-----------------------------------
Response Headersview source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="e10cce5997514651851aa4fe5f21c26f"
Content-Length:3632612
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Wed, 06 Feb 2013 18:45:04 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 05 Feb 2013 20:15:20 GMT
Server:CherryPy/3.2.0
```

Has anyone else expierenced this? I'm willing to do further tests as requested as well.

Answer (score 3):

You may fix this problem by doing the following:
There is an option in chrome://flags called "Disable hardware-accelerated video decode" enable it.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/chrome/mp4/chrome/ilqhiTTZcaY/hkPGA3GK6BIJ

And this is a bug filed three weeks ago: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?view=rev&revision=178906. According to its status it is “Fixed”.  However, later on in the comments it is saying the fix might be pushed for version M25 and is fixed with version 26.0.1395.1.

As a test, I have downloaded version 26 of Chrome (the developer version), (re)disabled the “Disable hardware-accelerated video decode”, and everything works fine.  If you want to do the same, visit Chrome’s release page and choose “Dev channel for Windows”.